# Exception Description: Syntax error parsing

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpql

I'm beginner Java programmer

I want to run a query with JPQL, but I give an error message

error message

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select u from user u where u.email = :pr1 and u.password = : pr2]. 
[27, 64] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1583)
    ... 85 more
```

query

```
@EJB
    private UserFacade usersfacede;
    private String redirect;

    public void dologin(){

        String query1 ="select u from user u where u.email = :pr1 and u.password = : pr2";
        List<User> loginuser = usersfacede.araStr(query1, email.trim(), password.trim(), "", "", "");

        if(loginuser.size()>0){
            Util.setSessionAttribute("name", loginuser.get(0).getName());
            redirect="index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }else{
            redirect="";
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("error",  "") );
        }
    }
```

make UserFacede extends AbstractFacade

arastr function in AbstractFacade.java

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.entity;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author seref
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public List<T> araStr(String sorgu, String pr1, String pr2, String pr3, String pr4, String pr5) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sorgu);
        if (pr1 != null & !"".equals(pr1)) {
            query.setParameter("pr1", pr1);
        }
        if (pr2 != null & !"".equals(pr2)) {
            query.setParameter("pr2", pr2);
        }
        if (pr3 != null & !"".equals(pr3)) {
            query.setParameter("pr3", pr3);
        }
        if (pr4 != null & !"".equals(pr4)) {
            query.setParameter("pr4", pr4);
        }
        if (pr5 != null & !"".equals(pr5)) {
            query.setParameter("pr5", pr5);
        }
        System.out.print(query.toString());

        List<T> list = query.getResultList();

        return (List<T>) list;
    }


    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

Does someone know where is error?

Comment: There is a space between the colon and the `pr2` in your query in the method `doLogin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query from

```
select u from user u where u.email = :pr1 and u.password = : pr2
```

to

```
select u from user u where u.email = :pr1 and u.password = :pr2
```

i.e. remove the space between : and pr2.

Comment: its worked thanks. its simple error I beginner too in java :)